# Setting a CONST inside a FLATLIST/VIEW

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How would one set a const inside this VIEW statement ?

every time I try to do this, I get hit with an unexpected token issue for either line.

Any ideas ?

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.theContainer}>
    <FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    keyExtractor={(x,i)=>i}
    renderItem={({item}) =>
      <View>
            {
              const fm = (item.featured_media);
              const theMediaLink = `https://example.com/json/media/${ item.featured_media }`;
            }
            <Image source={fm} />
            <HTMLView
              value={item.title.rendered}
              styles={styles.topicTitle}
            />
            <HTMLView
              value={item.excerpt.rendered}
            />
      </View>
    }
    />
  </View>
);
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer in order to better explain what your problem is.

Comment: why dont you send renderItem to the function?

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, it would be awesome if you would accept it ;)

Comment: Wow Martin! Thanks! I upvoted it. I accepted your answer! Thank you sir. That certainly clarifies things. Clearly I am a noob. ;-) I'll figure out the rest of my errors with this code. But it clearly works at this point. However as it turns out the image link that I thought I was going after isn't an image link. I now have to go back and do a second pull against the data source's media tree for the GUID that's related to the first pull and the concatenate everything together. But you showed me how can I do that within the renderItem. :-)

Comment: Berkay, I think sending it to a function would be much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. You cannot define variables within a jsx statement like this. But you can slightly restructure your code and than it should work:

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.theContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.topicTitle}>TANGOTOPICS.COM</Text>
    <FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    keyExtractor={(x,i)=>i}
    renderItem={({item}) => {
      const fm = (item.featured_media);
      const theMediaLink = `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/${ item.featured_media
      return (
        <View>
          <Image source={fm} />
          <HTMLView
            value={item.title.rendered}
            styles={styles.topicTitle}
          />
          <HTMLView
            value={item.excerpt.rendered}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    }
    />
  </View>
);
}
```

To clarify the difference to your render method:

You are rendering the View using the function `renderItem()` which is a arrow-function implicitly returning `<View>`:

```
renderItem={({item}) =>
      <View>
            {
              const fm = (item.featured_media);
              const theMediaLink = `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/${ item.featured_media }`;
            }
...
```

This way, the const declarations are within the return statemant, which is not valid in Javascript. In my example, I do not implicitly return any value from `renderItem()` instead I first declare the consts and then explicitly return the `<View>`:

```
renderItem={({item}) => {
      const fm = (item.featured_media);
      const theMediaLink = `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/${ item.featured_media
      return (
        <View>
...
```

To illustrate the difference even further, arrow-functions work like this: if you put an expression right behind the arrow, it will implicitly return  this expression:

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
```

If you put your expression within curly brackets like below, you have to return explicitly

```
// doesn't return anything
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { expression }
// returns the expression
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { return (expression) } 
// above is equivalent to:
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
```

I hope this helps.